# What i am looking for is when i use datepicker with sqlite, how do i use the date as a condition to show up in my listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, datepicker

```
private void show() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=dbconn.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c=null;
    c=db.query(TABLE_NAME,COLUMNS,null, null, null, null, null);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c, COLUMNS, TO);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    startManagingCursor(c);
    db.close();

}
```

I want to list in this `ListView`, make a condition, grab the `db date`, and then only get the day of the information, how can i do ?

Comment: `public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.dp);

                String date = dp.getYear()+"/"+(dp.getMonth()+1)+"/"+dp.getDayOfMonth();
                String note = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.note)).getText().toString();

                    insert(date, note);

                ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.note)).setText("");
            }`

Comment: grab the date and get day of information ?? please clarify ...

Comment: I would like to pick a certain date, add some information in that date, and then select a different date, do not appear other date information.

Comment: you want to filter from query or process after the result??

Comment: which one? your question is not clear

Comment: from sqlite and filter

Comment: loop over your cursor and process each cursor data if valid

Comment: Your question is too broad. Break it down into pieces, Where exactly you r having problem. You need help to pick date from Date Picker or need help to extract Day or need help to build query. Also specify your table schema and how are you storing dates in that table. Always try to break problem into smaller problem then only people will understand you and can offer help

Comment: I hope to use the datePicker to display the note based on the date the user selected. I'm sorry.